# Cypress : not able to add Ignore X-Frame headers extension from chrome

Tags: google-chrome-extension, cypress

Basically, I want to overcome the CORS exceptions in my testing site as it uses a different superdomain on the login page, for that I set `chromeWebSecurity` to false. But after that, I was getting another issue

> Refused to display 'XXXXXXXXX' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.

For this one, I added the Chrome extension 'Ignore X frame headers' and it was working perfectly. But in the Azure DevOps CI pipeline, I am getting the same issue and not able to add 'Ignore X frame headers' as I added it to my testing browser from the web store.

To add the extension to the testing browser before it launches, I tried the below solution

https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1763

I have extracted the CRX file and added it to the folder Ignore-X-Frame-headers_v1.1 and the below code for plugins/index.js .

```
 module.exports = (on, config) => { on("before:browser:launch", (browser = {}, args) =>
 {  if (browser.name === "chrome") { 
args.push("--disable-features=CrossSiteDocumentBlockingIfIsolating,CrossSiteDocumentBlockingAlways,IsolateOrigins,site-per-process"); 
args.push("--load-extension=cypress/extensions/Ignore-X-Frame-headers_v1.1");
 return args; } }); };
```

Also, set the chromewebSecurity to false in cypress.json

```
"chromeWebSecurity":false,
```

I am using the following versions,

- Cypress:3.8.0
- Chrome: Chrome 79

Answer (score -1):

Finally, the issue is resolved. We should provide the absolute path for the extension and it doesn't take the relative path when it loads the extension to the browser hence the browser was not able to find out the exact file for the extension.